# adding two images as one figure but how to rename them induvial

Tags: tables, captions

I know how to add two images as one figure but I don't know how to rename them individually. For example, the first one is 'a' and the second is 'b', this way I can explain in the caption.

```
\begin{figure}[h] \label{...}
    \centering % Horizontally center the figure
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Gaopaper_cQED} % Include the figure
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Gaopaper_cQED-2} % Include the figure
    \caption{The engineering cycle of a cQED device}
\end{figure}
```

I have tried tabular too but got this error message '! Undefined control sequence.'

```
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=0.20]{Resonator2-ANSYS-renderer}} &
\subfloat[b]{\includegraphics[width = 0.20]{Resonator2-ANSYS-Efield}}
\caption{ a) A resonator with ANSYS... b) The same ...}
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: You could load `subcaption` package and put each `\includegraphics` inside a `subfigure` (`\begin{subfigure}{0.49\linewidth} ... \end{subfigure}`). Then add a `\caption`, and if needed a `\label` in each `subfigure`.

Answer (score 2):

The go-to package for sub-captioning would be the [`subcaption` package](//ctan.org/pkg/subcaption). It provides the `\subcaptionbox` macro for setting a sub-caption that you can reference if needed. Here's a use case showing the basic setup:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\captionsetup{
  subrefformat=parens
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{Left\label{fig:fig-left}}[.4\linewidth][c]{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\quad
  \subcaptionbox{Right\label{fig:fig-right}}[.3\linewidth][c]{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}%
  \caption{Main figure caption}
  \label{fig:fig}
\end{figure}

See Figure~\ref{fig:fig}.

See Figure~\ref{fig:fig-left} and~\ref{fig:fig-right}.

See Figure~\ref{fig:fig}\subref{fig:fig-left} and~\subref{fig:fig-right}.

\end{document}
```

Lots of customizations are possible. See the [`subcaption` documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/documentation) for more.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked just perfectly! :)